# Find $\dim_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{Q}[x]/((x+1)^2)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> What is the dimension of the ring $R=\mathbb{Q}[x]/((x+1)^2)$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$?

My try:

Let $I=((x+1)^2)$. Using division algorithm we can say $R=\{(a+bx)+I~|~a, b \in \mathbb{Q} \}\cong \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$.

Hence $\dim_\mathbb{Q} R=2.$

Is this a right approach? Please mention if I've made any mistake.
Does this method works for polynomial of degree $n$, I mean, can we say:

> If $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$  is of degree $n$, and $R:=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f(x))$, then $\dim_\mathbb{Q} R=n.$

Comment: Your approach is corrcet.

Comment: Thank you so much...

Comment: @Hanual Jeon ..So can I tell.. $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f(x))$ is acutally n copies of $\mathbb{Q}$....And this result similarly holds for $\mathbb{R}[x]/(f(x))$ is basically Euclidean Space $\mathbb{R}^n$..??

Comment: As a _vector space_, ${\mathbb R}[x]/(f)$ is indeed isomorphic to ${\mathbb R}^n$. As _rings_, however, they are not.

Comment: Yes ...Thanks...@Magdiragdag